# Error in open another website with jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to open another website in my site with jquery ajax, but this error happened:

[image: console error]

[image: Error]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var success = function (data) {
            data = $.parseJSON(data);           
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://www.anothersite.com',
            data: { todo: "jsonp" },
            dataType: "jsonp",
            contentType:'application/text',
            crossDomain: true,
            cache: false,               
            success: success,
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                //alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });
</script>
```

please help me!

Comment: You've told the `$.ajax()` method that you expect the response to have `dataType: "jsonp"`, but clearly the response is HTML...

Comment: It's not clear from what's given what you are trying to do, are you appending a full html response to your page? Why not just use an iframe?

Comment: @nnnnnn what is solution to solved it?

Comment: @sarepta i dont want to use iframe!

Comment: i want process on respone as string but happend error and i cant get response data!

Comment: without  ' dataType: "jsonp" ' , not working to open another website!

Comment: Obviously, the problem occurs because `'http://www.anothersite.com'` return HTML instead of JSON !

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH realy, i want to get data another site with jquery(client side), how?

Comment: What type of data ? the website allows cross-domain ajax requests ?

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH type of string (convert html page to string), yes allows! i use 'dataType: "jsonp" ' to cross-domain!

Comment: You can use `$.get`. take a look at this example: https://jsfiddle.net/3567ze9a/

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH i used this but happened error, No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource, how set access?

Comment: It means that the remote website doesn't allow cross-domain requests !

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH Is it possible to active it? what is solution?

Comment: You are the owner of the remote website ?

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH yes, both is my website.

Comment: You need to add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header to your remote server response.

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH how do it?

Comment: What type of server you have (remote one) ? what language are you using?

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH both server is windows and my language is asp.net mvc c#

Comment: Okay, take a look at this http://enable-cors.org/server_iis7.html

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH  thanks, solved

Comment: Don't post images of text.